# Last character gets unspanned after applying two spans on a selected text in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, spanned

This problem is pretty annoying so Iam going to trace it down bit by bit so you can understand it fully:-

First I select the last word in my edit text like so:-

[image]

So far so simple then I make the text bold by clicking a button (setting a bold span) like so:-

[image]

The underline is just the default text correction in the softkeyboard. Then I reselect the text:-

[image]

Then when I make it italic the same way (setting italic span by pressing a button) I get this:-

[image]

The last character gets unspanned from bold .This happens only in this specific situation when I **select** the word and the word is at the **end** of the edittext.

Also I found out that this problem occurs when the spans are set for each char if its for the whole word it doesn't happen (for both bold and italic):-

```
//for each char
for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i++) {//token is the word
SpannableString char = (SpannableString) token.subSequence(i, i + 1);

char.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 
char.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

But if whole word problem doesn't happen:-

```
// for the whole word 

token.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 
token.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

But of course the user can set spans for a char so the problem is still relevant else no problem occurs if the word is not selected at the end of the edit text .

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution by adding a space char after the last index before extracting the selection token.

```
selectionStart = noteview.getSelectionStart();
selectionEnd = noteview.getSelectionEnd();

if(noteview.hasSelection()&&selectionEnd==noteview.length()) {
SpannedString sp=SpannedString.valueOf(" ");
edittext.setText(TextUtils.concat(edittext.getText(),sp));
}
```

> Sometimes the simplest solution is the best solution :).